# Как сделать так, чтобы определенный PHP скрипт в элементе width заменял запятую на точку?

Tags: php, css, замена, width

Как сделать так, чтобы определенный PHP скрипт в элементе width заменял запятую на точку?
Пример:
Из этого: width: 33,333333333333%;
В это: width: 33.333333333333%;
Это для прогрессбара/онлайнбара.

вот скрипт:

```
if( ($tInterval >= $checkDel) AND ($sCheck == $iter) ) {
        if( $socket = @stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$host.':'.$port, $erno, $erstr, $tOut) ) {
            @fwrite($socket, "\xFE");
            $data = @fread($socket, 1024);
            if( strpos($data,"\x00\x00") != 0 ) {
                $info = explode("\x00\x00", $data);
                $info = str_replace("\x00", '', $info);
                ###
                $plOnl = $info[4];
                $plMax = $info[5];
                $colBar = $onClass;
            } else {
                $info = explode("\xA7", $data);
                $info = str_replace("\x00", '', $info);
                $plOnl = $info[1];
                $plMax = $info[2];
                $colBar = $onClass;
            }
            @fclose($socket);
        } else {
            $plOnl = 0;
            $plMax = 0;
            $colBar = $offClass;
        }
        unset($data);
        unset($info);
        $checkServ = $iter+1;
        if( $checkServ >= count($server) ) {
            $checkServ = 0;
        }
    } else {
        $plOnl = $comData[$name][1];
        $plMax = $comData[$name][2];
        $colBar = $comData[$name][3];
    }
    $fullOnl += $plOnl;
    $newMon[$name] = array(
        1 => $plOnl,
        2 => $plMax,
        3 => $colBar
    );
    if( $colBar == $offClass ) {
        $onBar = $offWidth;
    } else {
        $onBar = ($plOnl/$plMax)*100;
        if( $onBar > 100 ) {
            $onBar = 100;
        }
    }
```

Вот вставка в HTML:

```
<div class="OnlineBar <?php echo $colBar;?>" style="width: <?php echo $onBar;?>%"></div>
```

Comment: ```srt_replace``` или ```preg_replace```

Comment: Подскажите, где это надо вставить и как должно выглядеть. Я дополнил вопрос. Буду очень благодарен.
P.s. я лютый чайник

Comment: Я правда хотел бы вам помочь, но сделать больше чем дать ссылку на документацию по функциям - значит решить задачу за вас, а я ни коим разом не могу отобрать у вас прекрасное чуство достижения цели и решить эту задачу за вас, вот [документация](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: заменить `<?php echo $onBar?>` на `<? printf('%.2F', $onBar)?>` или `<?= number_format($onBar, 2, "", ".")`, а реплейсы это костыль